# Modify CSS property of every element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm currently trying to create a 'page modifier'. Simply put this is a web page what contains an `object` element with `data` property set to a desired page.

The issue I'm having is with modifying elements within this object. I've got 3 `div` elements on my page (`topArea`,`MainBodyArea`,`ControlHostArea`) - `MainBodyArea` contains the object with an id of `LoadedPage` (which is the element used to display the desired page).

I've got a button (input type button, not `<button>`) with an id of `ApplyStyle`. I've tried something like this;

```
$("#ApplyStyle").click(function(){
  $("#LoadedPage").find("*").css("border", "2px solid red");
});
```

For some reason which isn't immediately apparent, this doesn't change anything about the elements within `#LoadedPage` - there's no indicator that the element style properties have changed at all.

I've tried the following code with my own website (http://www.innuendo-eu.co.uk);

```
$("#ApplyStyle").click(function(){
  alert($("#LoadedPage").find("#menu-nav").css("border"));
});
```

The alert that appears is simply 'undefined' (`border` isn't defined on that element, but I tried with 'margin' as well which is defined but the alert returns the same 'undefined'). I guess I'm trying to interact with the page elements incorrectly.

I should clarify I'm adding 'LoadedPage' dynamically when a user clicks a different button;

```
$("#LoadPage").click(function(){
  $("#MainBodyArea").html('<object id="LoadedPage" style="height:100%; width:100%;" data="' + $("#txtDestPage").val() + '">');
});
```

If I call an alert with `LoadedPage` width property before it's created, it'll return undefined, but clicking it after it's created will return the defined value.

What I want to do is figure out where I'm going wrong with element interaction and how I change (as per the example) the border of each element within `LoadedPage` to be "2px solid red".

Answer (score 0):

You're closing the multi-quote wrong; try

```
$("#ApplyStyle").click(function(){
  $("#LoadedPage").find("*").css("border", "2px solid red");
});
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. I corrected that when I realized a moment after posting but alas the same issue still remains.